# about users who ask, then answer and vote for themselves

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, etiquette, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Am i the only one who find it's absurd to allow a user to answer to his own question, then vote to his own answer and accept it as the right answer?

as this one:

[How to add shadow to a group of CALayer using CATransform3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966568/how-to-add-shadow-to-a-group-of-calayer-using-catransform3d)

Isn't this a way to encourage users to spam stackoverflow with questions/answer just to get easy extra reputation points?

Comment: @gnat : thanks for your comment. i can read there: "users can answer their questions (but not earlier than 48 hours after asking the question)." . But i found today an answer posted just a minute after the question, that's why i wondered if there were something wrong...

Comment: The 48-hour minimum time limit is for _accepting_ your own answer, not for posting it.  Maybe the answer in the other thread should be edited to make that clearer.

Comment: I dismissed your flag by the way. No harm done.

Comment: @meronix note another statement there: "only restriction is placed on new users with less than 100 reputation; they are not able to do so for the first 8 hours since the question was asked. No such restriction exists if you have more than 100 reputation..."

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: yes, thanks, now it's clearer how it works... and with these rules now it's clear why i can find around users with 2 login-name, to vote one each other

Comment: See also: ["Encyclopedia Stack Exchange"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)

Comment: @meronix: If you have evidence of voting circles like that, by all means flag a post for a Moderator to look at. (Be sure to use the "other" option to detail your suspicions.) Note, though, that the serial-vote-reversal algorithm usually finds and deals with these situations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your statements are a bit misguided.

1. The user doesn't get the +15 rep for the accepted answer if they're answering their own question.
2. The user can't upvote or downvote their own answer, ever.

Comment: thanks, that make sense